# My wordpress site is gone after new 4.2 wordpress update - Video Mag from Orange Themes

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have tried to update a site I'm working on for someone and I got the white blank screen during wordpress update. I did not back up...

I tried to change the name of the plugins folder as advised by someone but that didn't work. I could be something to do with a theme or something else. Does anyone know potential ways to fix this?

Comment: Too broad question. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: What kind of info would help you advise me @ericbn?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling plugins is a good start and will work much of the time, but since it hasn't, *see sections below on defaulting to the twentyfifteen theme and doing a manual upgrade.*

These are general "upgrade done gone wrong" instructions from the [WordPress › Support » READ THIS FIRST – WordPress 4.2 Master List](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/read-this-first-%E2%80%93-wordpress-42-master-list?replies=5)

1) Flush any caching plugins you might be running, as well as server and/or browser caches.

2) Deactivating all plugins (yes, all) to see if this resolves the problem. If this works, re-activate the plugins one by one until you find the problematic plugin(s). If you can't get into your admin dashboard, try resetting the plugins folder by [FTP](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients) or PhpMyAdmin (read ["How to deactivate all plugins when you can't log in to wp-admin"](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_to_deactivate_all_plugins_when_not_able_to_access_the_administrative_menus.3F) if you need help). Sometimes, an apparently inactive plugin can still cause problems. Also remember to deactivate any plugins in the mu-plugins folder. The easiest way is to rename that folder to `mu-plugins-old`

3) Switching to the Twenty Fifteen theme to rule out any theme-specific problems. If you can't log in to change themes, you can remove the theme folders via [FTP](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients) so the only one is `twentyfifteen`. That will force your site to use it.

4) Manually upgrading. When all else fails, download a fresh copy of the latest.zip file of 4.2 (top right on this page) to your computer, and use that to copy up. You may need to delete the wp-admin and wp-includes folders on your server. Read the 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress#Manual_Update Manual Update directions first.

Comment: Thank you @songdogtech. I will try the above. I am not sure though what you mean by flush caching plugins. I did deactivate a caching plugin already few days ago as it was not allowing me to update the css file.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is within filters.php file - another user has figured it out and it worked for me. I believe it applies to all or several of Orange themes. Please comment out this code from the filters.php file ( within functions folder )

```
function get_avatar_url($get_avatar){
    if(preg_match("/src='(.*?)'/i", $get_avatar, $matches)) {
    preg_match("/src='(.*?)'/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
    } else {
    preg_match("/src=\"(.*?)\"/i", $get_avatar, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
    }
}
```